# Merging two data frames with flexible conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Counterparty':['Bank','Client','Bank','Bank'],
            'Maturity':[200, 400, 200, 400],
            'Amount':[100, 100, 100, 100],
            'Factor':[0,0,0,0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Counterparty':['Bank','Client','Client'],
            'Maturity_Condition':['*', '<50', '>=50'],
            'Factor':[1,0.5,0.7]})
```

Based on the conditions set in the df2 dataframe, I want the factor in df1 to be populated. IF there is a '*' , then that condition should be ignored. So, based on the data in df2, If the counterparty is a bank, the factor is always 1 ( immaterial of maturity). However, if the counterparty is client, depending on maturity, the factor should be either 0.5 or 0.7. For the example above, I want to achieve:

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({'Counterparty':['Bank','Client','Bank','Bank'],
            'Maturity':[200, 400, 200, 400],
            'Amount':[100, 100, 100, 100],
            'Factor':[1,0.7,1,1]})
```

Besides using a boolean mask and a complex if statement list, does anyone have a more elegant way of achieving the above ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to merge the dataframes and then apply the conditions to the rows and keep the ones that meet the conditions:

```
>>> df_merged =  df1.merge(df2,how='left',on=['Counterparty']
                           ).merge(df2,how='left',on=['Counterparty'])

>>> df_merged    

   Amount Counterparty  Maturity  Factor Maturity_Condition
0     100         Bank       200     1.0                  *
1     100       Client       400     0.5                <50
2     100       Client       400     0.7               >=50
3     100         Bank       200     1.0                  *
4     100         Bank       400     1.0                  *
```

Let's replace the `*` condition by a condition that's always `True`:

```
>>> df_merged['Maturity'].astype(str) + 
    df_merged['Maturity_Condition'].replace('*','!=np.nan')

0    200!=np.nan
1         400<50
2        400>=50
3    200!=np.nan
4    400!=np.nan
```

And create a mask where conditions met:

```
>>> mask = (df_merged['Maturity'].astype(str) + 
            df_merged['Maturity_Condition'].replace('*','!=np.nan')
            ).apply(eval)

>>> mask =
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
```

Finally, apply the mask to select the rows meeting the condition and select the columns:

```
>>> df_merged[mask][['Counterparty','Maturity','Amount','Factor']]

   Amount Counterparty  Factor  Maturity
0     100         Bank     1.0       200
1     100       Client     0.7       400
2     100         Bank     1.0       200
3     100         Bank     1.0       400
```

Hope it serves.